# A p-dimensional Column Space and Linear Independence of an n $\times$ p Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

Here's the question.

Let $A$ be an $n\times p$ matrix whose column space is $p$-dimensional. Explain why the columns of $A$ must be linearly independent.

I came up with the following answer.

If $Col(A)$ is is $p$-dimensional, then $rank(A)=p$ and $nullity(A)=0$ by the Rank-Nullity Theorem. This means that all $p$ columns of $A$ form a basis for some $p$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$, since if there was at least one column of $A$ that wasn't part of the basis for $Col(A)$, then $nullity(A)\gt 0$. But if the columns of $A$ form a basis, then the columns must be linearly independent by definition of a basis.

Is this sound logic?

Comment: Is there a typo in the statement? Should it be "$A$ is a $n\times p$ matrix whose column space is $n$-dimensional" or "$A$ is a $p\times n$ matrix whose column space is $p$-dimensional"? Because for a $n\times p$ matrix with entries in $\Bbb R$, its column vectors are elements of $\Bbb R^n$

Comment: The textbook says it as I typed it. It's not a typo as far as I know. I changed what the columns form a basis for if that helps.

Comment: @PrasunBiswas I think the statement is fine as is; it's saying that $A$ has full column rank. Obviously for this to hold, we must have $p \leq n$ since the column space is a subspace of the codomain $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: @Bungo: I came to the same realization just seconds ago. Still, thanks for confirming! :)

Comment: @XStanton - "This means that all $p$ columns of $A$ form a basis for $\mathbb R^n$"... you can't conclude that. You can only conclude that the columns of $A$ form a basis for the column space of $A$, which may be a proper subspace of $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: @XStanton: The crux is one part of the replacement theorem: a spanning set of a $p$-dimensional subspace can be reduced by one for every linearly dependent vector it contains, ie, it can be reduced to exactly $p$ elements. Since there are exactly $p$ column vectors of $A$ and the column space is $p$-dimensional, it must be that the column vectors of $A$ are linearly independent, otherwise you can remove a member from the spanning set and it will still span the same subspace, but a $p$-dimensional subspace cannot be spanned fully by less than $p$ elements.

Comment: @Bungo- I changed up a bit of the answer to "a p-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Is it valid now?

Comment: How are you getting from a column not being part of a basis when put with the rest to the nullity being positive? Prove that

Comment: The original question implies that the matrix has full rank, meaning the rank of $A$ is equal to the number of columns, which is $p$ in this case. The Rank-Nullity Theorem states that $rank(A)+nullity(A)=p$. If $A$ is of full rank, then $nullity(A)=0$. If $rank(A) \lt p$, $nullity(p) \gt 0$. Since the rank of $A$ is determined by how many vectors are in any given basis of the column space, if one of the $p$ columns of $A$ isn't a part of the hypothetical basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$ created by the other columns of $A$, then $rank(A) \lt p$, which contradicts the assumption in the question.

Comment: Your title is not information, and even though it clearly indicates you are taking the problem verbatim from *somewhere*, you have failed to indicate what that source is. Please fix your title and make the full citation; otherwise, you're just being a bad tease.